# How can I fix drivers for Ralink RT3290 WiFI and Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, bluetooth, ralink

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. The WiFi driver is unstable, sometimes it dips the upload/download rate to nearly 0 and recovers after a few minutes, The Bluetooth is not recognized in settings.
Hardware: Asus N56JN, Ralink RT3290 WiFI and Bluetooth.

[Wireless Info all-in-one script pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aRJkbbYG)

Comment: Did it ever work or did it start acting up after a kernel update?

Comment: Bluetooth never worked, in the settings it says "No Bluetooth Found". WiFi sometimes works perfect, sometimes you must wait minutes for a webpage to load (on my phone WiFi works well, its not from the router). I didn't update manually the kernel, made only the updates from "Software Updater". now I'm on version 5.8.0-40-generic.